# Dataframe Convert rows to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my Dataframe:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| b | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |

I want to convert (b,c) and (d,e) columns rows to list

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can you detail the logic and explain how this could generalize with less/more columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple pandas `tolist()` function to combine multiple columns.

Your code should be like this.

```
import pandas
data = [('a','3','5','7','9'), ('b' ,'4','6','8','10')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'])

df['F'] = df[['B', 'C']].values.tolist()
df['G'] = df[['D', 'E']].values.tolist()

df_res = df1 = df[['A', 'F','G']]
print(df_res)

   A       F        G
0  a  [3, 5]   [7, 9]
1  b  [4, 6]  [8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

With [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)ing new columns:

```
new_df = (df.assign(F=df[['B', 'C']].values.tolist(), G=df[['D', 'E']].values.tolist())
         .drop(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], axis=1))
```

---

```
    A       F        G
0  a   [3, 5]   [7, 9]
1  b   [4, 6]  [8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic method to handle any number of column pairs:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('A').to_numpy().reshape(len(df), -1, 2).tolist(),
             index=df['A'], columns=['F', 'G']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A       F        G
0  a  [3, 5]   [7, 9]
1  b  [4, 6]  [8, 10]
```